# Plugin Visual Studio Code

Tags: plugins, visual-studio-code

In PhpStorm pressing `Ctrl + Click` on the function takes me to the place where it is implemented.

Is there some plugin that does this in Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Do you mean to view the function definition?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the PHP Intellisense extension, which provides "go to definition" support: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-intellisense

You can trigger it with F12 or ctrl+click.